# Sense HAT behaves strangely

Tags: gpio, pi-2, sense-hat

I have fixed my sense HAT after bending the male pins of the header. I used a https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/gpio-hammer-header Pimoroni Solderless GPIO Hammer Header

But I tested it and it behaved very oddly

At boot, a rainbow comes up, but keeps throughout the Pi being powered, and I can't program it

I checked how inserted the  header into the HAT, and it doesn.t fall off at all

Can I fix it, or should i just ignore it (I have an Enviro pHat, but it doesn't include: Humidity, LED Grid, Gyro and Magnetometer)

Note: I can't solder

Comment: is the rainbow a small square in the upper right? If so it is indicating under voltage. You need a better power supply or cable.

Comment: @SteveRobillard, it's a different rainbow, the Sense HAT LEDs light up in rainbow colours on boot

Comment: @SteveRobillard the whole grid lights up, but I'm suspecting it to be slightly dimmer...

Comment: The rainbow on the sense HAT on boot simply means it's powered. It should disappear shortly before the login prompt appears (or X starts). One cause of it not disappearing is I2C being disabled; you can ensure it's enabled with `sudo raspi-config`

Comment: @DaveJones I've enable I2C in raspi-config and rebooted my Pi. Still no luck

Comment: Okay, can you check if `/boot/overlays/rpi-sense.dtbo` exists? That's the device tree overlay for the sense HAT. If it's there try adding "dtoverlay=rpi-sense" to the end of `/boot/config.txt`. If it's not there you may have an ancient version of Raspbian in which case I'd suggest just flashing a new one

Comment: @DaveJones My program  that should clear the HAT white clears the HAT peach...

Comment: Glad the HAT's working now - but I think we'd need to see the code to determine whether that's an issue with the script or something else. Probably best to make that another question.

Comment: @DaveJones 'Tis now another question at: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61434/sense-hat-clears-with-wrong-color