# Sense HAT clears with wrong color

Tags: pi-2, sense-hat

Here's my code:

`from sense_hat import SenseHat
 hat = SenseHat()
 hat.clear(255, 255, 255)`

What should clear the HAT white clears it peach

Why is this?

Comment: Have you tried lighting each LED individually to see what you get? For example run your code with hat.clear(0,0,255) to observe the blue LED then run it again with hat.clear(0,255,0) to observe the green LED... and so on.